# Need advise. How to validate forms with AJAX and not to create excess load on server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

Well, hello everybody, I faced with a big problem which I can't solve.
So, here is it: I need validation, but I have **my own expectations towards it.**

So, what I do:
***Here everything goes right as I suppose...***

1. I get the values from fields (e-mail(text input), username(text
   input), sex(radio btns),  birth date(select lists),
   password&repeat_password(password inputs).
2. Then I handle and validate those values. For example: I check if email is not empty, if it fits the pattern, if birth date is right and real, if password fits needed limitations. *Another words, here I validate all params without AJAX, just using custom JS*.
3. After validation, I get the responses from each field with messagies of validation result and the result(Boolean) itself.

   **HERE'S THE PROBLEM COMES UP**
   So, as I have results of validation, now I need to check *if EMAIL is UNIQUE and if USERNAME if UNIQUE.* This ofcs should be performed with AJAX, but IMPORTANT: I shouldn't perform request to server to check email if there were some problems with email before. If its OK, I send it. Same with username field.
   *AND FINALLY, validation is boundaried on onsubmit event, so I want to check email, username with no AJAX, then validate them on being UNIQUE if there were no errors before with them and then IF ALL fields are correctly validate, only at that case I send form, in other occasion I would like to use **event.preventDefault()*** .

So, due to AJAX works in async way, I can't use event.preventDefault inside it, so that's first problem. Also I cant return anything from ajax callback to let system find out if there were any validation issues or not.

**I am not asking for a solutions, I am not crazy, I understand that there is a lot to think about, BUT** *I want some of matured gyes helped me with advise, how to validate forms correctly using AJAX?* How to divide code on blocks in validation and make it reusable, using async AJAX?? Pls, I'm struggling a lot. I've already written a lot of code to validate fields with no ajax, and I dont understand how to relate them with ajax, send the form if everything OK.

Can u share your expiriance in validating forms, how do u usually do it? How have u learnt how to validate forms? **AND WHAT ARE BEST PRACTISES OF VALIDATING FORMS WITH AJAX?**

Comment: There are sooo many tutorials and examples around the inetrnet :/

Comment: can u share with me some of them?

Comment: _...can u share with me some of them?_ What about google?

Comment: Just search on google

Comment: Well, if I could find what I need at google I hadn't been writing here, so as u can imagine, I've tried.

Comment: Probably you have to try to search better ;)

Comment: Well, you won't be able to find a ready to use solution but you have to do a step by step research...write the code and come back with specific issues...

Comment: You should never rely on JS validation. It should always be crossed with server validation. 
You can use it for validations to not allow empty fields or with certain type of values, but it should always double check on the server. Specially for things like unique emails, etc. 
JS side validation is very easy to change for the client

Comment: @Nikita Have a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) || [Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) I can recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) as your little guide in learning Web Development. Helped me to understand a lot without having to research on various sources

Comment: Yeah, I know it. I beatifully understand that same data could be sent with CURL and them my validation would simply fail, cuz JS wont function. BUT, I've seen a lot of times the websites where fields were validated on flow with JS just to notify users about possible errors. So, and there the accecebility of email, username is also checked with ajax. So, I need to figure out how to validate fields on flow, but if smth go wrong prevent sending form, but at the same time I want to form beeing sent on script which is pointed in action attr if everything right.

Comment: Already watched that but thanks.

Comment: can u describe which technology are you working on , so i can help you with that ajax response thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it reaches form validation, there are a few things you should keep in mind:
 1. Importance of the transmitted information;
 2. How reliable it needs to be;
 3. How many requests you are going to have;
 4. How much information your form is going to hold;

In my honest opinion, I would use Javascript/Ajax for quick and more accurate paths in your form. For example:
 1. Validating date fields are in correct format;
 2. Validating ages are matching your requisitions;
 3. Validating a gender was selected (BTW it is `gender` you are looking for, not `sex`);
etc...

Anything that needs to be correct and secure on your website (specially passwords and emails, etc), if you want to validate such you should do it on your server. Always!

Now, if you form is too long, you can do a step by step registration, instead of all in one. You can keep the progress saved in the session (server side) and maybe use a cookie to inform your site that they started the registration before (for this you can use javascript);

**NOTE:** You should inform your user you are using cookies as it is mandatory due to GDPR :)

Both validations help making the user journey smoother. There are things you should defo use as Js validation for quick response and making sure user is aware of some mistakes before they submit the form.
Server validation is safer for the sensible data that you need to make sure is correct as user as no say in it.

But it really depends on what you are trying to achieve and how many resources you  have available to you.

[Ajax form validation overalls](http://michaelsoriano.com/how-to-ajax-validate-forms/)

[Form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Hope it helped clear some things up! :)

Comment: Thank you bro, such a helpful answer. If I have been entitled to rate answers, I would give u +1.

Comment: Glad I could help @nikita ^^

Answer (score 0):

use this

https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

this will help you to set all validation on client side, once fullfilled, it will hit the 'validation success call method' and then go to ajax,

You can also set custom validation like, minlength, maxlength,should contain, maxcheck, mincheck, email/phone formats , etc

revert if any problem

Comment: I'd suggest he should learn it the hard(plain) way, and then switch to a third-party-library.